# How to copy a selection of lines from file to file in Tcl?

Tags: parsing, tcl

I want to copy a selection of lines from a file to another file in Tcl, where regular expressions find the starting and finishing lines of the selection.
I tried this:

```
    while {[gets $thefile line] >= 0} {
       if { [regexp {pattern1} $line] } {
            while { [regexp {pattern2} $line] != 1 } {
                    puts $thefile2 $line
                    }
    }
```

The `pattern1` and `pattern2` are not always at the same line.
this is an infinite loop, but how to continue to wrote the lines until the second pattern is reached ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem with your code is that you weren't reading any new lines while handling your inner loop…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways. Either you nest loops (with an inner one copying) or you have some kind of flag to switch the behavior back and forth of a single loop.

### Nested loops

```
while {[gets $thefile line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp {pattern1} $line]} {
        while {![regexp {pattern2} $line]} {
            puts $thefile2 $line
            # Note: might attempt a [gets] *twice* on EOF
            if {[gets $thefile line] < 0} break
        }
    }
}
```

### Single loop

```
set flag off
while {[gets $thefile line] >= 0} {
    if {!$flag && [regexp {pattern1} $line]} {
        set flag on
    } elseif {$flag && [regexp {pattern2} $line]} {
        set flag off
    }

    # "off" and "on" are booleans
    if {$flag} {
        puts $thefile2 $line
    }
}
```

You might be able to simplify the code to switch modes by removing the tests for whether the flag is set or not at that point; you only have to be careful if the same line could be matched by both patterns.